# How to add a custom root certificate MS Edge on Linux

Tags: certificates

I have to use MS Edge on Linux, and I need to my company's internal ca root certificate public key to validate internal sites.

The security section in Settings there is a "Manage certificates" link, but that does not work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

MS Edge is a Chromium based browser and uses a similar private store as Chromium.  Edge uses a keystore in `~/.pki` and you need the `certutil` utility program.

For Ubuntu and Debian:

1. `sudo apt install libnss3-tools`
2. `certutil -d sql:$HOME/.pki/nssdb -A -t "C,," -n <certificate nickname> \ -i <certificate filename>`

Reference:

- https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromium/src/+/master/docs/linux/cert_management.md
- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Projects/NSS/Reference/NSS_tools_:_certutil